working with TrustZone environment how can i communicate with the SMC API
i am starting a new project concerning trustZone cortex-A ,and i am having a bit of hard time to understand the technicalities lets say i want to communicate directly with the SMC for some non-secure , secure world communications
how would i build this how would i debug the system and see the communication happening  between these 2 worlds so i can debug and start understanding the system  better using gem5 in ARM architecture
Thank you in Advance
i did a gem5.opt system for ARM architecture and started running trusted firmware-A using VExpress_GEM5_Foundation that is running firmware-A on EL3 following the steps from this link
https://community.arm.com/arm-research/b/articles/posts/running-trusted-firmware-a-on-gem5

You have three large subjects.  1. Trustzone.  2. Trusted firmware 3. The GEM framework.  Gem is not a factor to your question (directly).  In your link, there are BL3.1, BL3.2 and BL3.3.  You can also see 'PSCI', 'SCMI' and 'SPD' and firmware updates SMC.  These are ARM standards for doing different task between non-secure (now rebranded REE) and the secure (brand TEE).  Can you please specify which SMC interface you wish to use and show research into these interface types.  Whether GEM is a sufficient model checker is another topic.

Also, this Q/A on Trustzone, TEE and ATF maybe helpful.  Linux PSCI bindings, and Linux SCMI bindings.  They reference the ARM docs as a primary source as well. ARM's SMCCC gives a generic overview of partitioning in the SMC space (ARM tends to change URL locations over time).

@artlessnoise i very much appreciate your response  Thank you i found the links you mentioned really useful   as for your answer i am still i am still figuring it out the whole idea of my project is to find a similar attack to return to user attack on trust zone -A profile basically researching of any kind of buffer overflow that i can control the return addresses in between communication of these 2 worlds

@artlessnoise but i am in kind of a loop with the environment setup that i am kind of stuck in creating the whole process since that link i mentioned before had kernel with a  really minimal features i cant test anything or debug anything yet since i need a working environment with gem5 , i need gem5 since its part of my project

The main attack is buffer overflows on SMCCC generic calls.  Each SMCCC call is a 'C' routine and the parameters from the 'normal world' (REE) should be sanity checked before use (like user space kernel data) before use in the 'secure world' (TEE).  If you are not trying to do power supply/clock glitches, then the PSCI and SCMI bindings are not useful.  From the SMCC page you can see 'world switch' code and look at the BL3.1 is monitor mode and it has the SMC handler.  This vectors to callers like an os SYSCALL.  Your attack vectors are the parameters to the routines.

@artlessnoise i pretty much appreciate this information Thank you so much i will be digging into it

@artilessnoise as i went deeper into what you suggested and Now my question is
in my attack i need to write a c code running on the trusted firmware that would call a secure world service, that i could buffer overflow and rewrite its return address.  the process would work in if i wrote a c code from the normal world  that basically calls a secure service  which should have a vulnerable function like memcpy for overflow to succeed correct ?

as i understood the SMCC are basically conventions that how the parameters of the SMC are called. last thing where can i find the secure services in the source code and where do u suggest me to look in

Your understanding of a an attack of the TZ SMC API is correct.  You need buffers or buffer sizes.  A simple integer for calculations is not a threat (eg a value to memset memory to).  If you have secure world API code, you can also look to see how buffer sizes, etc are checked.  The location of the secure world SMCC will be different system-to-system.  So, no one can answer without specifics; it is such and such android phone running software version xx.yy.zz, etc.  This is not appropriate for stack overflow, you should find the code through your own research. Q/A on identified code is okay.

@artlessnoise Thank you again for all your help,  i agree with you my response was ambiguous  i am working on Arm trusted firmware based on the Armv8-A and Armv7-A architectures. https://github.com/ARM-software/arm-trusted-firmware basically what i am trying to figure out is how can i find the secure services since i need the secure function ID to call it from a normal world c routine program using smc

https://github.com/ARM-software/arm-trusted-firmware/blob/master/bl32/tsp/tsp_common.c
